# Indexed View vs. Aggregate Table

Tags: data-warehouse, etl

It appears that indexed views and aggregate tables are used for the same purpose: To precompute aggregates in order to improve query performance. What are the benefits to using one approach over another? Is it ease of maintenance when using the views versus having to maintain the ETL required for the aggregate table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using SQL Server, so here are some points to consider.

- Indexed view may or may not contain aggregations.
- There is a list of functions (operators, keywords) **[that can not be used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx)** in indexed views, many of them aggregate.
- Indexed view binds schema to tables referenced by the view.

Also, disabling an index on the view physically deletes the data. In data-warehousing, all indexes are usually dropped or disabled during loading. So, rebuilding this index would have to re-aggregate whole table after every major (daily?) load -- as opposed to an aggregate table which may be updated only for a last day or so.